# load and freeze one model and train others in PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, torchvision

I have a model A that including three submodels model1, model2, model3.

the model flow: model1 --> model2 --> model3

I have trained model1 in an independent project.

The question is how to use the pre-trained model1 when training the model A?

Now, I try to implement this as follow:

I load the checkpoint of model1 by `model1.load_state_dict(torch.load(model1.pth)) and then set the requires_grad of the model1’s parameters as False?

Is it right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct.

When you structure your model the way you explained, what you are doing is correct.

ModelA consists of three submodels - model1, models, model3

Then you load the weights of each individual model with `model*.load_state_dict(torch.load(model*.pth))`

Then make `requires_grad=False` for the model you want to freeze.

```py
for param in model*.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

You can also freeze weights of particular layers by accessing the submodules, for example, if you have a layer named `fc` in model1, then you can freeze its weights by making `model1.fc.weight.requres_grad = False`.